# How to deal with dirty data without decreasing the generalization power of the model?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm working on a sequence labeling task using a conditional random field. My training data has some errors in it. These are not errors in the sense of having tokens that have incorrect labels. Instead, some of the tokens have typos in them. Not surprisingly, the labeler tends to get incorrect results when testing on the data that contains typos.

I can't decide if it would be better to leave the typos in there or take them out. A possible benefit of keeping the typos as they are is that the training data would then more accurately represent the real world data that the labeler will be used on. On the other hand, I fear that training on lower quality data will result in a lower quality labeler.

Is there a standard practice or conventional wisdom regarding this sort of problem?

Forgive me this question is considered too subjective for this forum. I just discovered this site today.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I have changed the header in an attempt to make the question more precise. Please check that the meaning (or your intention) has not been changed.

Comment: As I have understood the question, the typos do not occur in labels (response variable), but only in the predictor variable aka terms. Is this correct ?

Comment: Thanks for adjusting the title. And yes, your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true that the training data should be the as close as possible to the data the model will be applied on eventually.

But as you said, cleaning the input data automatically by fixing typos via spellcorrector or normalizing synonyms to one term will improve make the data more "precise" for the classification task.

However, to make the model learned on preprocessed data applicable to unlabeled data, one need to attach these preprocessing steps to the model itself, so that the preprocessing performed during training is also performed before the prediction of the labels. Seen from the outside, data with typos is feed into a blackbox (containing preprocessors and model) both during training and application.

=> No bias is introduced.

Comment: I do this to some extent already, but unfortunately, I don't think I'd be able to get rid of all the typos. Perhaps it would be better to make the features that I generate for each token be more robust against small errors. Thanks for the feedback!